# Язык программирования Perl

Tags: perl

пример отсюда -> http://citforum.ru/internet/perl_tut/syntax.shtml

```
$var = 1;
$var2 = 3 if $var > 0;
```

**;** почему не стоит после **3** ?, а стоит после условии...

А почему условие присваивется к переменной ? почему отдельно не написать ? как это может быть полезно ?

Comment: Можно и if ($var >0) {$var2 = 3}, если больше нравится C-style. TMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 5):

Ларри Уолл, лингвист и заодно создатель языка perl решил сделать его похожим на английский язык. В Английском языке принято писать "*assign var2 5 if var > 0*" ("Присвоить var5 пять, если var больше 0") поэтому и язык perl унаследовал такой синтаксис записи одиночных условий. Условие пишется после выполняемого действия, без каких либо разделителей вроде точки с запятой, в случае если действие одно. И да, это очень не привычно, по сравнению с большинством других языков программирования.

Указанную строку можно написать на perl минимум двумя способами:

```
$var2 = 3 if $var > 0;  # Первый способ, унаследованный от английского

if $var > 0 {           # Второй способ, фигурные скобки обязательны.
    $var2 = 3           # А вот точка с запятой после единственного выражения внутри блока скобок
                        # не обязательна, но может и присутствовать
}
```

Оба этих варианта абсолютно равнозначны и выполняют одно и то же, пишите так, как вам больше нравится.

P.S. По замечанию @nörbörnën добавлю, что само по себе наличие фигурных скобок в конструкции (а они требуются во втором варианте) могут накладывать ограничения связанные с областями видимости. Так как любой блок в фигурных скобках в perl имеет собственную лексическую область видимости, то переменные объявленные лексическими (my) или статическими (state) внутри блока, окажутся не доступны снаружи. А локальные (local) вернут свое изначальное состояние за пределами блока. Так же может меняться поведение некоторых других конструкций, зависящее от лексических областей видимости.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Майк, второй способ нельзя назвать равнозначным первому из-за того, что область видимости переменной $var2 ограничивается блоком в котором она объявлена и, значит, если $var2 объявлена внутри условного оператора то она не будет видна вне его. я понимаю, что ты это знаешь, но считаю, что в ответе этот нюанс должен быть упомянут

Comment: @Tiny пожалуйста, пометьте ответ принятым

Comment: @nörbörnën Но var2 внутри блока не объявлена и используется из внешней области видимости. Если мы находимся в строгом режиме - то получим ошибку времени компиляции, об использовании не объявленной глобальной переменной (так как нет упоминания, что она например my), если мы ошибку не получаем, значит она была объявлена ранее и нормально видна. Если же мы в не строгом режиме, без требования объявления переменных, то $var2 будет доступна и вне этих фигурных скобок, даже если первый раз встретилась внутри них.

Comment: хорошо-хорошо :) при `use strict;` `my $var2 = 3 if $var1 > 0` не равнозначно `if ($var1 > 0) { my $var2 = 3; }`

Comment: @nörbörnën Замечание написал, но мне кажется это все таки немного в сторону от основного вопроса. А то так придется дописывать замечание про работу use/no, потом еще разные модули упоминать которые вводят собственные конструкции ...

Comment: но это ведь и есть особенности применения этой конструкции. вообще, особенности её поведения неоднократно оговариваются в документации, например, "NOTE: The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, my $x if ...) is undefined. The value of the my variable may be undef, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.". так что "Here be dragons", которых нет в `if ($var > 0) { BLOCK }`